# En consulta utilizar 2 campos de diferente registro con la misma tabla SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Gracias por la ayuda antes que nada.

Actualmente me encuentro trabajando en una base de datos donde tengo las siguientes tablas:

En la tabla `recibos` (Almacena los datos asociados al recibo= nro_recibo, fecha, codempresa). Esta tiene relación con la tabla `recibos_dt` a través del campo `reca_pk` donde utilizando esta relación hago un join para obtener el campo `va_referencia` de la tabla `vale_asis`, que esta enlazada  a la tabla `recibos_dt` por el campo `va_Det_pkp`. Lo cual necesito para relacionar 2 facturas que están enlazadas en la tabla recibo.

Cuando me refiero enlazadas, se trata de que los montos del recibo esta dividido en 2 partes:

- Un monto de comprobante que se entrega a una empresa.
- Otro monto de comprobante que se entrega al cliente que recibe. (Para fines de contabilidad).

Ejemplo: Recibo no 001 Empresa1

```
    Cantidad    Monto    Empresa1   Empresa2

           1    12500       10000       2500 

       Total    12500       10000       2500
```

recibo no 002 empresa2 (Los números de recibo no están relacionados)

```
    Cantidad    Monto    Empresa1   Empresa2

           1    12500       10000       2500 

       Total    12500       10000       2500
```

Existen dos recibos dado que en ocasiones el monto para alguna de las empresa de algún articulo puede ser 0. (Si la empresa uno tiene el monto total asociado no se crea el recibo de la empresa 2).

Necesito realizar una consulta donde obtenga todos los recibos que están asociados al campo `va_referencia` (deberían ser siempre 2), entonces utilizar estos dos recibos en el mismo registro.

**Nota**.

Esta es la consulta actual que estoy utilizando:

```
Select recibos.nrorecibo
     , recibos.co_empresa
     , recibos.cod_cliente
     , vale_asis.va_referencia
       From recibos
          , co_empresa
          , cod_cliente
          , vale_asis
       Where recibos.va_pk = vale_asis.va_pk 
         And recibos.reca_pk = vale_asis.reca_pk 
         And vale.va_pk = vale_asis_det.reca_pk;
```

Actualmente esta consulta me trae todas las facturas incluyendo la de empresa y cliente.

[image: Resultado de la consulta actual.]

Al final si es posible realizar mi consulta sería algo como esto: Siendo el recibo 1 el de la empresa y el recibo 2 el del cliente respectivamente.

```
nrorecibo1  nrorecibo2     co_empresa   cod_cliente
       001         002        empresa       cliente
```

Muchas gracias por ayudar.

Esto me tiene días con la cabeza loca.

Comment: Un consejo: si tiene mas de dos tablas, puede incluir el ER diagram para que ser mas facil entender la pregunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si me entiendo correctamente, la solucion es anadir un consulta `GROUP BY`:

```sql
select min(a.nrorecibo), max(a.nrorecibo), a.co_empresa, a.cod_cliente from
(
    -- su consulta aqui
    Select recibos.nrorecibo
        , recibos.co_empresa
        , recibos.cod_cliente
        , vale_asis.va_referencia
        From recibos
            , co_empresa
            , cod_cliente
            , vale_asis
        Where recibos.va_pk = vale_asis.va_pk 
            And recibos.reca_pk = vale_asis.reca_pk 
            And vale.va_pk = vale_asis_det.reca_pk;
) a
group by a.co_empresa, a.cod_cliente, a.va_referencia
```

Comment: Saludos Luke,Efectivamente la solucion que recomiendas soluciona completamente mi problema. No te imaginas agradecido y lo aliviado que me pone esto. Realmente al final tuve que hacer una pequeña modificación retirarando a.co_empresa del group by  porque me estaba dando dos lineas con los numeros de recibo max y min repetidos , pero luego de eso  funciona perfecto , perfecto. 

muchas gracias por tomar el tiempo de leer toda ese Periodico que he escrito arriba.. pulgar arriba.

Comment: @marinoalbertoHernandezsever recuerda que puedes marcar la respuesta como aceptada si resolvió tu problema. Sólo es hacer clic en el _tick_ que está bajo el indicador de votos positivos/negativos y dejarlo verde